# an error occured using nuxt3 + element plus

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

tried to learn nuxt3 and element plus is dependencis I used to, but using all together

some had a dependency problems

this is error message

in the index.vue file using element ui components then got an error

```
ERROR  Error while requiring module @element-plus/nuxt: TypeError: _dayjs.default.extend is not a function                                                                                                   

 ERROR  Cannot start nuxt:  _dayjs.default.extend is not a function                                                                                                                                           4:44:34 PM
  at node_modules/element-plus/es/components/time-picker/src/time-picker.mjs:10:16
  at jiti (node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:245784)
  at node_modules/element-plus/es/components/time-picker/index.mjs:1:2184
  at jiti (node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:245784)
  at node_modules/element-plus/es/components/calendar/src/date-table.mjs:2:1
```

here is package.json file

```
{
  "name": "nuxt",
  "version": "2.0.2",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev --dotenv .env.development",
    "start": "nuxt start --dotenv .env.production",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/color-mode": "^3.2.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "npm:@sxzz/popperjs-es@^2.11.7",
    "apexcharts": "^3.36.3",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.2",
    "element-plus": "^2.3.4",
    "feather-icons": "^4.29.0",
    "vue3-apexcharts": "^1.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.16.3",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^12.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^12.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/google-fonts": "^3.0.0-1",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.6",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.2.6",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.11",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "element-plus": "^2.3.5",
    "eslint": "^8.37.0",
    "nuxt": "^3.5.3",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.5",
    "pinia": "^2.0.27",
    "postcss": "^8.4.23",
    "prettier": "^2.8.7",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "typescript": "^5.0.3",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.2.0",
    "@element-plus/icons-vue": "^2.1.0",
    "@element-plus/nuxt": "^1.0.5"
  }
}
```

tried different version of dependencies but got stuck for weeks